# Using Surv() function in R for left censored data and cox regression

Tags: r, regression, survival-analysis, cox-regression, survival

I want to do a survival analysis and cox regression for metastasis data to see if there are any significant genes associated with early metastasis.
The data set has gene names as columns, time at first visit, time at last follow-up, status (metastasis present or not), time (interval between first visit and follow up). The values of the gene columns are 0 or 1 to indicate Wild type or altered. So the columns for the data would be: TP32, EGFR, KRAS, MYC,..., FirstVisit, LastVisit, Time, Status.
The time at last follow up column would be the time at first metastasis presentation if metastasis occurred, and if no metastasis occurred, he last follow-up date.
Normally, I would code the survival analysis and cox regression like this:
`coxph( Surv(time, status) ~ gene1 + gene2 + gene3 +..., data = my_df)`
How would you do a left-censoring for this scenario, and how would you handle patients who already have metastasis at first visit? Would you just completely exclude them?
How to repeat this analysis with Death as a competing risk?

for a normal competing risk with cox regression, would this work?
coxph( Surv(time, status) ~ gene1 + gene2 + gene3 +..., data = my_df) except status would have values of 0, 1, or 2 with 2 indicating a competing event (Death) occurred

Comment: The data situation you present is right-censored. Not sure what you mean by "how to do left censoring" because you don't have left-censored data. Sounds like you need the sort of advice that is dispensed at https://CrossValidated.com

Comment: If the time to first diagnosis is large and the sample has metastasis already present, this is a case of left censoring right?

Comment: I suppose you could say it is but I don’t see how such a case adds information to the analysis. You want cases where the time at risk before an event of interest is available.